# vue application does not update when using webpack chunks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import, chunks

I have a mysterious behaviour here using webpack in a vue-application.

I have some view-paths stored in my database and I import the views in a for-loop dynamically like

```
for(let i = 0; i < routesList.length; i++) {
    const viewPath = routesList[i];
    const view = () => import('views/' + viewPath);

    /* create a vue router object here */
}
```

This works absolutely fine but as soon as I am using `WebpackChunkName` **all the future changes** in my vue-files **does not get compiled**. The application seems to use some sort of cached files. Although npm watch recognizes the changes and recompiles correctly.

```
const view = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "views" */ 'views/' + viewPath);
```

Another strange thing to notice is that the chunk gets named like

- `views0`
- `views2`
- `views4`
- etc.

The application runs on a Debian 8 distribution. These are the output-settings of my `webpack.mix.js` file

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'demo'),
    publicPath: '/demo/', // due to shared hosting
    filename: `[name].${mix.inProduction() ? '[chunkhash].' : ''}js`,
    chunkFilename: `[name].${mix.inProduction() ? '[chunkhash].' : ''}js`
}
```

Has anybody faced something similar? Really I am clueless about what is wrong... I even tried to delete the compiled chunks and `mix-manifest.json` in the output folder and recompiled it over and over again. But this does not change the situation.

Related

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2530
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/875
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/885

**//Edit**

- 9/27 - Regarding the related issues on github there could be a
  problem with my paths in the webpack config file?
- 9/28 - Looks like this happens irregular. Updating my npm packages yesterday caused this to work for a moment. Today I'm stuck at the same again.